# Visibility of function overloads with different scope

Tags: c++, overloading

The code below gives error: `error: ‘double& Sample::GetValue()’ is protected within this context  |   double v = ms.GetValue();`. If the protected function if deleted it compiles fine. Is it the bug of the compiler that cannot select the correct function overload with different scope?

```
class Sample
{
public:
    Sample() {}
    virtual ~Sample() {}
    const double& GetValue() const {return v;}
    void Print() {std::cout << v << std::endl;}
protected:
    double& GetValue() {return v;}
private:
    double v;
};

class Sample2
{
public:
    Sample2() {}

    void Compute()
    {
        double v = ms.GetValue();
    }

private:
    Sample ms;
};
```

Comment: The two functions **are** in the same scope. They have different **access specifiers**, but that doesn't affect overload resolution. The protected version is the better match. Full stop. Same thing if it was private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What The Dreams Wind said, but the compiler doesn't know you want to call `const double& GetValue() const` (which should be `double GetValue() const`, btw) because `ms` is not declared `const`.

There's an easy fix though:

```
void Compute()
{
    const Sample &const_ms = ms;
    double v = const_ms.GetValue();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PMInVAfXKoosoAJ8)

Answer (score 3):

Visibility of a function doesn't alter overload resolution rules. There is no error here, `double& GetValue()` is simply a better candidate than `const double& GetValue() const`